# Numbers V3: If cell contains a value, convert cell value to X

Tags: numbers

I have a spreadsheet which contains a mixture of text strings and empty cells. I'm looking for a formula to replace the value of all non-empty cells with a single character 'x', while leaving empty cells blank.

Comment: Please specify if you want to keep the original values.

Comment: No need to keep original values. Just convert the string to an X.

Comment: Please, specify this point within your original question (OQ) and not within comments. Comments are destined to be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Daniel's tips I've come up with this solution:

1. Create an auxiliary column
2. Add the formula:

   IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),"x"," ")
3. Copy formula to all rows.
4. Overwrite original column with values from auxiliary column.

This isn't an ideal solution as I need to apply it individually to around 20 different columns. If anyone knows a way to do this without using an auxiliary column I'd be interested to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints:

- use an auxiliary column;
- use functions ISBLANK and IF;
- replicate the auxiliary column within the original one;
- remove the auxiliary column.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Daniel. I'd prefer not to use an auxiliary column if possible as I have around 20 columns that I need to apply the formula to.